# Why python returns 0 when rounding a floating point number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to round a floating point number but it returns zero. Why is that? How can I round my floating point number to 3 digits after decimal?

```
>>> a= 9.907283855185141e-32
>>> round(a,3)
0.0
>>> type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Did you notice the e-32 at the end?

Comment: `9.907...e-32` is the same as `0.0000...9907...`.  That `e-32` means "times 10 to the negative 32`.  That is an extremely small number that rounds to 0.

Comment: Yeah it was me missing e-32 at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number `a`, if written in decimal, is

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000009907283855185141
```

If rounded to 3 digits after the decimal, it is in fact `0`.